# Static noise in microphone only when webcam is on

Tags: microphone, webcam, 21.10

I'm having this weird issue ever since updating to Ubuntu 21.10 (I know it's not stable, but had to update due to work). The microphone works fine when recording with `arecord` or online recording tools, but as soon as I turn on the webcam it starts making a very loud static noise, this happens in google meet, and even local recording tools. I've tried messing around with `pavucontrol`, `alsamixer` with no success. Any help is appreciated.

laptop is a thinkpad yoga 370, the problem is with built-in webcam and microphone.

Comment: Can you use a seperate USB camera? Sounds like the built-in camera (or possibly the microphone) has a hardware problem.

Comment: Where do you get Ubuntu 21.10 is not stable? Some reference please.

Comment: same issue with my laptop Lenovo with 22.04